# Prolog outputs that a variable's value is the name of the other variable if they have the same value rather than the value

Tags: list, prolog

I am having a LOT of trouble with prolog because the professor is requiring us not to use base cases. I finally got my segregate predicate to work except that it says Even = Odd rather than Even = [] like it is supposed to. Is there any way around this?

```
segregate(List, Even, Odd) :-
   (not(length(List, 0)) ->
    % segregate the list
    ;
    Even = [],Odd = [], true).

?- segregate([], Even, Odd). 
Even = Odd, Odd = []
```

Comment: I don't think you understand how the `if -> then ; else` syntax works. Also please explain what your code is actually supposed to do, I have no idea why `Even = []` is what you want.

Comment: The best way to start defining a predicate is to give **ground** test cases where your relation holds. And (if possible) non-ground cases where it does not hold.

Comment: Not using base cases when writing recursive predicates seems to be quite a curious requirement...

Comment: I understand how it works, my segregate program works in its entirety. I wouldn't even call the Even = Odd incorrect, I just want to know if there is a way to avoid it. I don't want to post my entire solution so as to avoid it being copied, at least not until I turn it in. Segregate separates the elements of List into sublists Even and Odd, each of which contains the respective even and odd elements of List. I'm pretty sure the base case requirement is to avoid students copying online solutions. Even = [] for the base case where List is the empty list.

Comment: This is not a general Prolog question. This output will depend on your system. I would have thought it should be just `Even = [], Odd = []`

Comment: Why do you want to avoid this particular representation of an answer subsitution? It is very useful for big terms and long lists where it is difficult to tell if they are the same or not.

Comment: In that case you can just add `Even = Odd` to the query.

Comment: Ah yes. If the professor cannot teach you Prolog, they must at least impress upon you that, if it is hard for them, it will be harder for you, and therefore they are smarter than you.